# Where do I place the image data files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a ruby on rails project with a requirement of creating a Deal model with an image associated with it, it has other attributes as well but I want to focus on the image aspect. I was thinking about implementing the model by having an attribute called image_file_name. This string will contain the name of the image file. I will store the image file in the folder /app/assets/images. Is this the right way to go about things? I feel that this is the wrong place to place data related files within the application. Where would I keep such image or other media data within the project folder(If I am not using a 3rd party service like AWS).

Comment: It depends on the asset system you are using. do you use webpacker or someting else?

Comment: @OuttaSpaceTime How would I check that? I am sorta new to Rails and I just want to make sure I learn to do things the right way.

Comment: The main question here is really if the images are uploaded by the users or if its a developer concern. `app/assets/images` is really only for images that are a part of the app itself (the design). For user uploads you really want to look into ActiveStorage before you reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @max Isn't Active Storage primarily for Cloud Storage or is it also used usually for regular disk based data storage.

Comment: @redd ActiveStorage uses a disk based storage backend by default.

Comment: @max Okay. Thanks!